# I want to perform automatic playback when loading with WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, media, wkwebview

In `Objective-C`, we developed an application using `UIWebView`.
Among them, the automatic reproduction of media was realized with the following sources,

```
[self.webview setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
```

An error will now appear when changing from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`.

> No visible @interface for 'WKWebView' declares the selector
>   'setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:'

How can I fix it?
Please tell me if you understand.

Answer (score 4):

`WKWebView` `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` is deprecated so you need to replace it with `WKWebViewConfiguration` `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback` like below.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
theConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = false;
```

Yo can't add `WKWebView` directly to in your `ViewController`, you need to add it programatically like below.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
theConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = true;
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

**Use Above code or Below Code**

If you want to change frame than use below, Here is full example code.

**ViewController.h File**

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productURL;

@end
```

**ViewController.m File**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.productURL = @"http://www.URL YOU WANT TO VIEW GOES HERE";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.productURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    theConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = false;
    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];  
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```